# How to add "Or" condition

Tags: javascript

I have this script:

```
else if (scrollTop < offsetTop2) {
        $("#p-contact-scroll").fadeOut(500);
        }
```

I need it to say if scroll top is less than offsetTop2 or scrollTop is greater than offsetTop3 fade "#p-contact-scroll"

I tried to write it like this but it gives me an "Unexpected token" error.

```
else if (scrollTop < offsetTop2 || scrollTop > offsetTop3) {
        $("#p-contact-scroll").fadeOut(500);
        }
```

My full script is like this: check if "#p-header" exists, which it does. if the id "#p-contact-scroll" scrolls past "#p-header" show, if its above "#p-header" hide. What I need to to add if "#p-contact-scroll" scrolls past ".elementor-element-53b9cbcc" hide regardless if its past "#p-header"

```
if ($("#p-header").length) {
    var offsetTop2 = $("#p-header").offset().top;
    var offsetTop3 = $(".elementor-element-53b9cbcc").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > offsetTop2){
        $("#p-contact-scroll").fadeIn(500);
    }   
    else if (scrollTop < offsetTop2) {
        $("#p-contact-scroll").fadeOut(500);
        }
    }); 
};
```

Comment: There's no unexpected tokens in code you've posted

Comment: The token error happens when I add the || to create the or

else if (scrollTop < offsetTop2 || scrollTop > offsetTop3)

Comment: Your if condition works:
https://jsfiddle.net/qzteabxd/

Problem is where you put data into the variables

Comment: Are you sure that .elementor-element-53b9cbcc doesn't change at runtime?

Comment: Im sure, currently it shows and hides fine it just wont hide when passing the div with the elementor class. Ideally I just need "#p-contact-scroll" to show when goes past div 1 and hide when going past div 2

Comment: I can confirm the short circuit is correct